# Modifying component's variable value through service

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a group component in my application named `CustomerListComponent` where in which I've a boolean variable named `isEligibleForBenefits` and which is defaulted to `false` while initializing.

Now I'm in a situation where I need to invoke a `REST` call in one of my service and on the success event of that call I need to make this `isEligibleForBenefits` variable to true.

The question here is, manipulating a group component's value from a service allowed?, If so how can that be achieved?

Can someone help?

Comment: Use  rxjs observable to notify the changes in your variable

Comment: You can implement a Message service based on observables to broadcast a message from your own service to the component

Comment: Thanks @iambatman and David I will check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay i will answer you briefly:

In you service that will make an api call:

```
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';


export class yourService {
     private messageSubject:Subject<boolean> = new Subject();

     public getMessageSubject():Subject<boolean>{
            return this.messageSubject:Subject;
     }


    private callApi(){
         http.whatEver.map(() => { this.messageSubject.next(true);})
    }
}
```

In your component:

```
export class yourComponent{
   constructor(private service:yourService){
      this.service.getMessageSubject.subscribe((value:boolean) => {
            this.isEligibleForBenefits = true; // or = value;
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks Nour! :-)

Comment: Glad to help! :)